# What exactly is label for image segmentation task in computer vision

Tags: computer-vision, mask, image-segmentation, pytorch, cross-entropy

I have been working on a some image segmentation tasks lately and would like to apply one from scratch.

Segmentation as I have understood is the per pixel prediction to where it belongs - to an object instance(things), to a background segment instance(stuff).

As per the COCO dataset on which the latest algorithm Mask RCNN is based :

> things are countable objects such as people, animals, tools. Stuff classes are amorphous regions of similar texture or material such as grass, sky, road.

As per the Mask Rcnn paper the final classification is a binary cross entropy loss function taking per pixel sigmoid (to avoid intra-class race). This pipeline is based on top of the FRCNN object detection pipeline from where it gets the Region-Of-Interest (roi) and passes them through a ROI-align class to keep the spatial information intact.

What I'm confused with is the following. Given a very simple code snippet below, for applying Binary Cross Entropy loss to separate 3 fully connected layers( some random experiment with scales):

```
class ModelMain(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config, is_training=True):
        super(ModelMain, self).__init__()
        self.fc_1 = torch.nn.Linear(incoming_size_1, outgoing_size_1)
        self.fc_2 = torch.nn.Linear(incoming_size_2, outgoing_size_2)
        self.fc_3 = torch.nn.Linear(incoming_size_3, outgoing_size_3)

    def forward(self, x):
        y_1 = F.sigmoid(self.fc_1(x)) 
        y_2 = F.sigmoid(self.fc_2(x)) 
        y_3 = F.sigmoid(self.fc_3(x)) 

        return y_1, y_2, y_3


model = ModelMain()
criterion = torch.nn.BCELoss(size_average = True) 
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr = 0.01)

def run_epoch():
    batchsize = 10
    for epoch in range(batchsize):
        # Find image segment predicted by running forward pass: 
        y_predicted_1, y_predicted_2, y_predicted_3  = model(batch_data_x)

        # Compute and print loss : 
        loss_1 = criterion(y_predicted_1, batch_data_y)
        loss_2 = criterion(y_predicted_2, batch_data_y)
        loss_3 = criterion(y_predicted_3, batch_data_y)

        print( "Epoch ", epoch, "Loss : ", loss_1, loss_2, loss_3)

        # Perform Backward pass : 
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss_1.backward()
        loss_2.backward()
        loss_3.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

... what exactly do we provide here as label?

From the dataset :

```
Formatted JSON Data
```

image :

```
 {
       "license":2,
       "file_name":"000000000139.jpg",
       "coco_url":"http://images.cocodataset.org/val2017/000000000139.jpg",
       "height":426,
       "width":640,
       "date_captured":"2013-11-21 01:34:01",
       "flickr_url":"http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8035/8024364858_9c41dc1666_z.jpg",
       "id":139
    }
```

Segment info :

```
{
   "segments_info":[
      {
         "id":3226956,
         "category_id":1,
         "iscrowd":0,
         "bbox":[
            413,
            158,
            53,
            138
         ],
         "area":2840
      },
      {
         "id":6979964,
         "category_id":1,
         "iscrowd":0,
         "bbox":[
            384,
            172,
            16,
            36
         ],
         "area":439
      },
      {
         "id":3103374,
         "category_id":62,
         "iscrowd":0,
         "bbox":[
            413,
            223,
            30,
            81
         ],
         "area":1250
      },
      {
         "id":2831194,
         "category_id":62,
         "iscrowd":0,
         "bbox":[
            291,
            218,
            62,
            98
         ],
         "area":1848
      },
      {
         "id":3496593,
         "category_id":62,
         "iscrowd":0,
         "bbox":[
            412,
            219,
            10,
            13
         ],
         "area":90
      },
      {
         "id":2633066,
         "category_id":62,
         "iscrowd":0,
         "bbox":[
            317,
            219,
            22,
            12
         ],
         "area":212
      },
      {
         "id":3165572,
         "category_id":62,
         "iscrowd":0,
         "bbox":[
            359,
            218,
            56,
            103
         ],
         "area":2251
      },
      {
         "id":8824489,
         "category_id":64,
         "iscrowd":0,
         "bbox":[
            237,
            149,
            24,
            62
         ],
         "area":369
      },
      {
         "id":3032951,
         "category_id":67,
         "iscrowd":0,
         "bbox":[
            321,
            231,
            126,
            89
         ],
         "area":2134
      },
      {
         "id":2038814,
         "category_id":72,
         "iscrowd":0,
         "bbox":[
            7,
            168,
            149,
            95
         ],
         "area":13247
      },
      {
         "id":3289671,
         "category_id":72,
         "iscrowd":0,
         "bbox":[
            557,
            209,
            82,
            79
         ],
         "area":5846
      },
      {
         "id":2437710,
         "category_id":78,
         "iscrowd":0,
         "bbox":[
            512,
            206,
            15,
            16
         ],
         "area":224
      },
      {
         "id":4159376,
         "category_id":82,
         "iscrowd":0,
         "bbox":[
            493,
            174,
            20,
            108
         ],
         "area":2056
      },
      {
         "id":3423599,
         "category_id":84,
         "iscrowd":0,
         "bbox":[
            613,
            308,
            13,
            46
         ],
         "area":324
      },
      {
         "id":3094634,
         "category_id":84,
         "iscrowd":0,
         "bbox":[
            605,
            306,
            14,
            45
         ],
         "area":331
      },
      {
         "id":3296100,
         "category_id":85,
         "iscrowd":0,
         "bbox":[
            448,
            121,
            14,
            22
         ],
         "area":227
      },
      {
         "id":6054280,
         "category_id":86,
         "iscrowd":0,
         "bbox":[
            241,
            195,
            14,
            18
         ],
         "area":187
      },
      {
         "id":5942189,
         "category_id":86,
         "iscrowd":0,
         "bbox":[
            549,
            309,
            36,
            90
         ],
         "area":2171
      },
      {
         "id":4086154,
         "category_id":86,
         "iscrowd":0,
         "bbox":[
            351,
            209,
            11,
            22
         ],
         "area":178
      },
      {
         "id":7438777,
         "category_id":86,
         "iscrowd":0,
         "bbox":[
            337,
            200,
            10,
            16
         ],
         "area":120
      },
      {
         "id":3031159,
         "category_id":118,
         "iscrowd":0,
         "bbox":[
            0,
            269,
            564,
            157
         ],
         "area":49754
      },
      {
         "id":9284267,
         "category_id":119,
         "iscrowd":0,
         "bbox":[
            338,
            166,
            29,
            50
         ],
         "area":842
      },
      {
         "id":6068135,
         "category_id":130,
         "iscrowd":0,
         "bbox":[
            212,
            11,
            321,
            127
         ],
         "area":3391
      },
      {
         "id":2567230,
         "category_id":156,
         "iscrowd":0,
         "bbox":[
            129,
            168,
            351,
            162
         ],
         "area":5699
      },
      {
         "id":10334639,
         "category_id":181,
         "iscrowd":0,
         "bbox":[
            204,
            63,
            234,
            174
         ],
         "area":15587
      },
      {
         "id":6266027,
         "category_id":186,
         "iscrowd":0,
         "bbox":[
            136,
            0,
            473,
            116
         ],
         "area":20106
      },
      {
         "id":5274512,
         "category_id":188,
         "iscrowd":0,
         "bbox":[
            0,
            38,
            549,
            297
         ],
         "area":25483
      },
      {
         "id":7238567,
         "category_id":189,
         "iscrowd":0,
         "bbox":[
            457,
            350,
            183,
            76
         ],
         "area":9421
      },
      {
         "id":4224910,
         "category_id":199,
         "iscrowd":0,
         "bbox":[
            0,
            0,
            640,
            358
         ],
         "area":83201
      },
      {
         "id":6391959,
         "category_id":200,
         "iscrowd":0,
         "bbox":[
            135,
            359,
            336,
            67
         ],
         "area":12618
      }
   ],
   "file_name":"000000000139.png",
   "image_id":139
}
```

The Mask image :

[image: Sample image 139 from coco dataset]
The Original image :

[image]

For the object detection task we have bounding box, but for image segmentation I need to calculate loss with the mask provided. 
So what should be the value for the  `batch_data_y` in the above code. 
Will it be the vector for the mask image.  But doesn't that train my network as to what color some segment is ?  Or am I missing some other segment annotation ?

Comment: Try printing the values in the mask image. It is possible that it contains color palette, and the values that it contains are actually class labels that you would expect.

Comment: As per the author, "The mask loss Lmask is defined only on positive RoIs.  The mask target is the intersection between an RoI and its associated ground-truth mask". 
Should I write an augmentation step to find the intersection between my two tensors ? 
The values are just pixel values, 3 channel image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intution of @Aldream was correct but explicitly for the coco dataset they provide binary masks, The documentation is not so great on their website :

> ## Interface for manipulating masks stored in RLE format.
>
> RLE is a simple yet efficient format for storing binary masks. RLE
>    first divides a vector (or vectorized image) into a series of piecewise
>    constant regions and then for each piece simply stores the length of
>    that piece. For example, given M=[0 0 1 1 1 0 1] the RLE counts would
>    be [2 3 1 1], or for M=[1 1 1 1 1 1 0] the counts would be [0 6 1]
>    (note that the odd counts are always the numbers of zeros). Instead of
>    storing the counts directly, additional compression is achieved with a
>    variable bitrate representation based on a common scheme called LEB128.
>   source : [link](https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi/blob/master/PythonAPI/pycocotools/mask.py)

Though I did write my own custom function for average binary cross entropy loss :

```
def l_cross_entropy2d(input, target, weight=None, size_average=True):

    n, c, h, w = input.size()
    nt, ct, ht, wt = target.size()

    # Handle inconsistent size between input and target
    if h > ht and w > wt: # upsample labels
        target = target.unsqueeze(1)
        target = F.upsample(target, size=(h, w), mode='nearest')
        target = target.sequeeze(1)
    elif h < ht and w < wt: # upsample images
        input = F.upsample(input, size=(ht, wt), mode='bilinear')
    elif h != ht and w != wt:
        raise Exception("Only support upsampling")

    # take per pixel sigmoid  
    sigm = F.sigmoid(input)
    # change dimension to create 2d matrix where rows -> pixels and columns -> classes
    # takes input tensor <n X c X h X w> outputs tensor < n*h*w X c >
    sigm = sigm.transpose(1, 2).transpose(2, 3).contiguous().view(-1, c)

    # change target to column tensor for calculating cross entropy and repeat it number of classes times
    # Get all values from sigmoid tensor >= 0 (all pixels that have value) 
    sigm = sigm[target.view(-1, 1).repeat(1, c) >= 0]
    sigm = sigm.view(-1, c)

    mask = target >= 0
    target = target[mask]
    loss = F.nll_loss(sigm, target, ignore_index=250,
                      weight=weight, size_average=False)
    if size_average:
        loss /= mask.data.sum()
    return loss
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @hkchengrex in his comment, the fact that the colors in the mask image seem picked from the real image is either coincidental, or the result of some post-processing for visualization.

Semantic masks are often represented/stored as images, with the value of each pixel representing the class(es) in the actual picture. For instance, assuming you are considering `C` classes, the semantic mask `M` of a picture `I` can be represented as an image where `M(i,j) = c` means that the pixel `I(i,j)` should be categorized as belonging to the semantic class `c` (`c` in `[0; C[` ; `i` in `[0, H[`, `j` in `[0, W[`, with `(H, W)` dimensions of `I`).

Now, since classes are independent from each other, the best way for a network to predict them is to output a probability map `P` of shape `(H, W, C)`, where `P(i,j,c)` represents the estimated probability (between `0` and `1`, hence an activation function like sigmoid) that `I(i,j)` belongs to the class `c`.

As you detailed yourself, with such an output, you can train your network using for loss a binary cross entropy -- given that you pre-process your grount-truth masks `M`, to convert them from `HxW` images with values in `[0,C]` (*logits*) into `HxWxC` maps with values in `[0,1]`. This pre-processing is called "one-hot conversion", and can be done with Pytorch using [`scatter()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.scatter_) c.f. this [thread](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/convert-int-into-one-hot-format/507/4):

```
import torch

M_onehot = torch.cuda.FloatTensor(C, H, W)
M_onehot.zero_()
M_onehot.scatter_(1, M, 1)
```

However, another solution -- maybe less adapted to your problem (if you want to avoid softmax, as it includes this operation) -- is the use of a (non-binary) cross entropy loss.
[`torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) would directly take `P` (of shape `(H, W, C)`) as prediction, and `M` (of shape `(H, W)`) as target.

Comment: From the paper : " The mask branch has a Km2-dimensional output for each RoI, which encodes K binary masks of resolution m×m, one for each of the K classes. To this we apply a per-pixel sigmoid, and define L mask as the average binary cross-entropy loss. For an RoI associated with ground-truth class k, L mask is only defined on the kth mask (other mask outputs do not contribute to the loss). "

Can you explain how to get the Km2 o/p. K =80 for the 80 classes in coco. But th m2 is it for entire image, or is every mask of every object detected a separate m*m tensor ?

Comment: If you replace `K` by `C` and `(H, W)` by `(m, m)` (they may be sub-sampling the masks compared to the input images), my answer provides some explanations already I believe. Basically your estimations/ground-truths are stacks of `K` tensors of size `(m,m)`. Each of the `K` sub-tensors represent the mask for its corresponding class (`1` if class certainly represented in this pixel/area ; `0` if class absent).